# How to detect that two Python iterators yield the same items?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, compare

Is there a concise and memory efficient way to find out whether two iterators `lines1` and `lines2` yield the same items?

For example, these iterators could be lines retrieved from a file object:

```
with io.open(`some.txt`, 'r', encoding='...') as lines1:
  with io.open(`other.txt`, 'r', encoding='...') as lines2:
    lines_are_equal = ...
```

Intuitively one could expect that

```
lines_are_equal = lines1 == lines2  # DOES NOT WORK
```

would give the desired result. However this will always be `False` because it only compares the addresses of the iterators instead of the items yielded.

If memory would not be an issue, one could convert the iterators to lists and compare them:

```
lines_are_equal = list(lines1) == list(lines2)  # works but uses a lot of memory
```

I already checked `itertools`, expecting to find something like

```
lines_are_equal = itertools.equal(lines1, lines2)  # DOES NOT WORK
```

but there does not seem to be any function like that.

The best I could come up so far is looping over both iterators using `itertools.zip_longest()` (Python 2: `izip_longest()`):

```
lines_are_equal = True
for line1, line2 in itertools.zip_longest(lines1, lines2):
  if line1 != line2:
    lines_are_equal = False
    break
```

This does give the desired result and is memory efficient however it feels clumsy and unpythonic.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Solution**: Applying the collective wisdom from the comments and answer this is the one line helper function that works even if the two iterators are the same or can have trailing `None` values:

```
def iter_equal(items1, items2):
  '''`True` if iterators `items1` and `items2` contain equal items.'''
  return (items1 is items2) or \
          all(a == b for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(items1, items2, fillvalue=object()))
```

You still have to make sure the iterators do not have side effects on each other.

Comment: What if the iterators are actually the same iterator, or if they're linked, so that advancing one affects the other?

Comment: Good point, to be more precise on the requirements: the iterators must be different instances (`lines1 is not lines2`) and have not side effects on each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) with generator expression:

```
lines_are_equal = all(a == b for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(lines1, lines2))
```

**UPDATE** If iterable can produce trailing `None`, it's better to specify `fillvalue=object()` as user2357112 commented. (by default `None` is used for fill values)

```
lines_are_equal = all(a == b for a, b in
                      itertools.zip_longest(lines1, lines2, fillvalue=object()))
```

If your purporse is to compare two files, not any iterables, you can use [`filecmp.cmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.cmp) instead:

```
files_are_equal = filecmp.cmp(filename1, filename2)
```

Comment: You'll probably want `fillvalue=object()`, in case the iterators differ by a number of trailing Nones.

Comment: I used the file example because it was trivial but the solution should work with general iterators.

Comment: @user2357112, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer to mention it.